# Sending an Email via Powershell script from PHP

Tags: php, powershell

I have a powershell script that sends an email which is being called from a php script.  Everything works great until I add the body parameter via a php variable. This line works:

```
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("C:\\path\\powershell.exe C:\\path\\email.ps1 \"{$email}\" \"Test Body"");
```

These next 2 both don't work:

```
$oExec5 = $WshShell->Run("C:\\path\\powershell.exe C:\\path\\email.ps1 \"{$email}\" \"{$body}\"");
$oExec5 = $WshShell->Run("C:\\path\\powershell.exe C:\\path\\email.ps1 \"{$email}\" {$body}");
```

I am very confused, at first I thought it had to do with the content of the variable but I feel I eliminated that possibility by setting $body="Test Body" the exact value that works when hard coded. I am stumped, please help.

Comment: if $email or $body contain shell metachars, and especially `"` chars, then you're going to be introducing command-line syntax errors.

Comment: yeah, I was kinda thinking it had something to do with that.  So obviously my email body is going to be a string, how can I add a php string variable to my powershell command line call?

Comment: you already are. what you need to do is make sure that the contents of your php variable are formatted so that they're seen properly by powershell. e.g. you're suffering from the shell equivalent of an sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: so when I echo the out "C:\\path\\powershell.exe C:\\path\\email.ps1 \"{$email}\" \"{$body}\"" the result is a line that I can copy and paste into powershell and it send the email, but it won't from php...not sure why

Comment: You need to build up the entire powershell command as a string literal with all your PHP variables escaped. Then pass that literal as the argument to the Run() method. And as @MarcB points out, make sure you escape any fancy metacharacters, or encode them.

Comment: I must me misunderstanding how this is done because it won't work for me, can you please provide an example?

Comment: So the problem seems to happen when I add a string with a space in it. No space, it works fine...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was pretty simple.  I added single quotes around the body message and my problem was solved.

```
$command = "C:\\path\\email.ps1 \"{$email}\" 'This is the body text'";

$oExec5 = $WshShell->Run("C:\\path\\powershell.exe {$command}");
```

The one problem I have found is that there seems to be a character limit on the length of text that I can put in the body message.